# apache error AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of -c/-C directives:

Tags: server, apache2, php

I recently upgraded to php56. Now I am unable to run apache.

I am getting:-

```
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.
```

when trying to run localhost

When I run the command httpd -t -c httpd.conf, it throws the following error:-

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 1 of -c/-C directives:
Invalid command 'httpd.conf', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

apachectl configtest does not throw any errors.
No logs in apache logs either.

Can anyone help me fix this. If you need any more details please tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.
It was because httpd.conf was unable to load libphp5.so
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
If I comment this. Apache starts working.

But it should've logged in the errors. Don't know why it didn't log any error.
Anyways thanks @FlorianDeish for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-f` instead of the `-c` switch to specify a config file, like

```
httpd -t -f httpd.conf
```

Make sure `httpd.conf` is the the current directory.

Comment: It says syntax OK